# Windows 8 speech to text and text to speech API

Tags: windows, windows-8, text-to-speech, voice-recognition, speech-to-text

I guess the question pretty much says it all?

And I would prefer not to access cloud services such as Microsoft Translator and Project Hawaii?

Is there any direct API I can access?

(For metro apps)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the [Microsoft Speech Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361572%28v=office.14%29.aspx) working on my Windows 7 laptop (both Voice Recognition and Text-to-Speech). You just need to install SDK and the runtime. You can also download additional Voice and Language packs. I would think it should work on Windows 8 as well. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.setinputtodefaultaudiodevice%28v=office.14%29.aspx) is a good sample on how to set it up to recognize some basic phrases like "Find restaurants near Seattle".

Comment: Seen it. I'm talking about for Metro Apps not Applications

Answer (score 2):

There are some new APIs for Windows 8.1:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.speechsynthesis.aspx

Text-To-Speech sample:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Speech-synthesis-sample-6e07b218

//build video on Channel9:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/2-171

Answer (score 1):

There are no Text to Speech or Speech to text libraries available in .Net for Windows 8 apps. System.Speech and such is not available. You will need to roll your own or find compatible 3rd party library.

I use Bing Translator service in my apps, but that has been removed from existance, they brought the text translator services into Azure, but did not bring speech over and they disabled the old website to get API keys for bing translator. Hadn't heard of Project Hawaii before will have to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft's speech API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125663%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) seems available in Windows 7.  Was it taken out of Windows 8?

Comment: Yep. It was taken out and Bing Translator has been depreceated

Answer (score 0):

You can now Access Bing Services for Windows 8 , the service has been just released and is in Beta1 stage

Comment: Okay I can't find this anywhere. I looked. Could you please provide a link?

Comment: Can't help you out much as I am on mobile but try this http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2012/10/03/bing-maps-sdks-for-windows-store-apps-now-available.aspx

Comment: Mark as answer if you find it useful .

Comment: Yeah. But these are Map API's. I'm looking for TTS APIs?

Comment: More services yet to come!!